# Native typeface can not be made - android

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

I already looked up other answers on this issue - they say assets/fonts should be  **inside** or outside of src/main.

But in my case I dont' have src or main folder:
[image: wwwww]

where should i put my assets/fonts folder in my case?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.iml file (under "app" folder), you will see a line of config

```
<option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
```

This means your "assets" folder is under "main" folder